# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'

Tags: fxm

I keep getting error below even after trying out all of these.

1. FXM.BaseHostDomain and  and FXM.hostname
2. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/150778
3. http://sitecoreinfo.blogspot.com.au/2017/09/sitecore-fxm-and-cors.html

> Failed to load
>   https://mainsite.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/ssc/Beacon/Service/beacon/trackPageVisit/?contactId=&sessionId=&page=https%3A%2F%2Ftargetsite.azurewebsites.net%2F&referrer=&rt=1526361067832:
>   Redirect from
>   'https://mainsite.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/ssc/Beacon/Service/beacon/trackPageVisit/?contactId=&sessionId=&page=https%3A%2F%2Ftargetsite.azurewebsites.net%2F&referrer=&rt=1526361067832'
>   to
>   'https://mainsite.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/ssc/beacon/service/beacon/trackpagevisit?contactId=&sessionId=&page=https%3A%2F%2Ftargetsite.azurewebsites.net%2F&referrer=&rt=1526361067832'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'https://targetsite.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Anyone faced this issue and got around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manged to fix this issue by steps below:

1. Make sure you get 200 response from this call. If you get 301, review your redirect rule which could be removing trailing slash. 
   https://mainsiteazurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/ssc/Beacon/Service/beacon/trackPageVisit/?contactId=&sessionId=&page=https%3A%2F%2Ftargetsite.azurewebsites.net%2Ffamilies%3Fsubcat%3Dpregnancy&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Ftargetsite.azurewebsites.net%2F&rt=1526366632093
2. And apply this custom header below:
   [image]